# How to order queryset with subset first

Tags: django

I have a form being rendered which displays questions to a test. I would like the checked, initial, values to be in the front of the queryset (the top checkboxes). Does Django have a function built in for this?

Code:

```
self.fields["questions"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Question.objects.all(), # here I would like to order_by('initial')
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    initial=self.instance.question_set.all()) # the initial checked values
```

Example:
If my queryset is [a, b, c, d] and my initial values in the form are [b, c] then the queryset would be ordered [b, c, a, d] so that the checked boxes show at the top of the form.

One way I have tried to go about it was removing all the initial values from the queryset then joining the 2 querysets as such:

```
# Get the initial instance values
initial_vals = self.instance.question_set.all()
# Get a list of IDs of the initial values
initial_val_list = initial_vals.values_list('id', flat=True)
# Filter out the initial values
questions_filtered = Question.objects.exclude(id__in=initial_val_list)
# Join the 2 querysets
qs = initial_vals.union(questions_filtered, all=True)

self.fields["questions"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=qs, # Use the newly joined qs
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    initial=self.instance.question_set.all())
```

This works but for some reason when I save the updated form it selects all the possible questions and adds them to the test.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you aim to do. Can you give some sample data together with the expected order?

Comment: I added an example of another way I tried to go about it. I essentially want the checked input fields in my update form to display as the first in the list of input checkbox fields.